# Does other functions inside the one which is attached using addEventListener also get attached?

Tags: javascript

I have this function in js:

```
function one(){

               function two() {};
               function three() {};
               element2.onclick = function {
                                  alert("alert");
               }

}
element1.addEventListener("click", one, false)
```

Along with `element1`, does the code above listens for the event on `element2` all the time as well?

Comment: Can't you test this and find out?

Comment: It does work, I just to be sure.

Comment: Your `addEventListener()` call is wrong; it should be `one`, not `one()`.

Comment: `element1.addEventListener("click", one(), false)` does not do what you think. It attaches a `undefined` to `element1`.

Comment: @pointy : Sorry for the typo, edited it and thanks.

Comment: @RaymondChen : Why undefined (politely asking), it does attaches. I thought, may be, I could attach more this way.

Comment: @ChiragRavindra : Thanks lot for explaining that! When I am testing, `element1` is an input box and `element2` is a button, and they are working properly. Even if I do multiple clicks on input box (`element1`) the  button (`element2`) seems to be behaving properly.

Comment: @Mr.President Yes, that would indeed be the way it works- I was mistaken. You were using `element2.onclick =` vs `element2.addEventListener` it would cause multiple callbacks in the latter case but not the former. (But the assignment still happens every time element1 is clicked but in this case overriding the previous handler because of the assignment and therefore not causing multiple callbacks to be invoked)

Comment: I'm not getting your question could you please explain once?

Comment: @ChiragRavindra: Thanks again. So, should I avoid doing this - `element2.onclick = function { alert("alert") }` . Could you, please, suggest a proper way.

Comment: @Mr.President there is nothing wrong in using it that way. It becomes a problem if you want to have multiple callbacks registered on an element for a single event - in that case, `addEventListener` allows you to do that (I'm more partial to `addEventListener` personally). The more problematic part was registering a click handler inside another click handler. While there may be legitimate reasons for this (ex: element2 should be clickable only after element1 has been clicked x times), in most cases, this would not be such a good idea

Comment: @ChiragRavindra : Thank you very much! I have a lot of code inside `function one()`. I would carefully remove them. I guess, I now understand what problems I could have faced in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Please check here through 1st button I'm initialize the 2nd button click event using addEventListener(). Run the code then click 1st button after that click 2nd button you'll get alert.

```html
<button id="myBtn1">Button1</button>
<button id="myBtn2">Button2</button>

<script>
function one(){
  function two() {};
  function three() {};
  document.getElementById("myBtn2").onclick = function() {
    alert("alert");
  }
}
document.getElementById("myBtn1").addEventListener("click", one,false)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `two()` and `three()` functions are never called. The code that they contain is never executed.

Every time when the `element2` is clicked, it'll assigned to a handler and that's a lot of repetition.